# Java: using a logger in JUnit assert*

Tags: java, logging, junit, assert

What I want to do is something like the following in JUnit:

```
assertTrue(logger.error("the condition is not true"), <a boolean condition>);
```

so the error message gets logged by a logger, where the logger could be e.g. commons or log4j.

But Junit asserts don't take a logger param, so is there some way to achieve this, or do I need to try-catch the assert and log the error message in catch block?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a JUnit [TestRule](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html) [TestWatcher](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html). A `TestRule` executes code before and after the test method (similar to `@Before` and `@After`), but you have access to more information, and more importantly, the result of the test. A [TestWatcher](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) defines methods like `succeeded()`, `failed()`, `starting()` and `finished()`, which you can implement to get notified of events.

The following example simply prints out the failed tests with the failed assertions.

```
public class TestWatcherTest {
  @Rule
  public TestWatcher testWatcher = new TestWatcher() {
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
      System.out.println("" + description.getDisplayName() + " failed " + e.getMessage());
      super.failed(e, description);
    }

  };

  @Test
  public void test1() {
    Assert.assertEquals("hello world", 3, 4);
  }
}
```

You can obviously do what you like instead of the System.out.println(). This produces as output:

```
test1(uk.co.farwell.junit.TestWatcherTest) failed hello world expected:<3> but was:<4>
```

Note that a failed assertion is an exception, so you'll have access to the stacktrace etc.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of JUnit introduced this?

Comment: @duffymo TestWatcher was introduced in 4.9, it was introduced as a replacement for TestWatchman, which itself was introduced in 4.7. TestWatchman is a slightly different thing, it uses MethodRule, which is now deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

I would not alter or extend the JUnit classes.

An arrangement where you try/catch and log errors would be preferable.

The problem is that failing an Assert is not necessarily an exception.

It feels like you're trying to make log4j into the reporting capability that already exists.  I'd advise that you look into the Ant JUnit reporting task - it'll give you a nice looking report that will be more useful than a log.

UPDATE:

You can always add another log4j file appender.  Let log4j write messages to both the console and the file that you choose.  No changes in your code at all if I'm correct.

Comment: well, what I want to do is control the output of JUnit asserts so I can send it e.g. to some DB for further analysis. Is there a way to do that using Ant JUnit reporting?

Comment: @duffymo A failing (junit) assert *is* an Exception, specifically an AssertionError. This is how JUnit works.

Comment: I never catch errors when I write JUnit.  I either code for the Assert to succeed or, in those cases where I expect an exception, I add the annotation to say so.  You might be right that JUnit is working that way under the covers, but I don't want to have to code to it.

Comment: @duffymo re: catching errors, me neither, except when I'm testing for them. I'm just trying to clarify that JUnit works like that under the covers. If you do an assert which fails, it will stop execution of the test method because an AssertionError has been thrown.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, Matthew.  I think we agree, except for the part about catching errors.  My preference is to use the @expecting annotation, but that's more of a style thing.  Your points about the newer annotations up above are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Better use this then

```
if(!<condition>) {
logger.error("my message");
Assert.fail();
}
```